# Grammar behind a train transfer announcement

Tags: grammar, particle-は

An example of a regular announcement on a train:

> 次は本町　本町　中央線　御堂筋線 **は** お乗り換えです

My main concern here is the second は (in bold). It does not seem to be a topic marker, it does not seem to be a binding particle (係助詞) as described in the answer to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28303/grammatical-construction-place%E3%81%AFsubplace-story-as-an-introduction), so what is the function of は here?

Why isn't the announcement using a destination particle に which is the usual particle used with the verb 乗り換える? Let's say something like this:

> 次は本町。本町は、中央線、御堂筋線 **に** お乗り換えです。

Also: where do the sentences in the original announcement start and end? Would 「中央線、御堂筋線はお乗り換えです」 be valid without a station name before? Or is it in fact 「次は本町。本町、中央線、御堂筋線はお乗り換えです」

Or (*added later*) if 中央線、御堂筋線 were a subject why isn't it:

> 次は本町、本町。中央線、御堂筋線はお乗り換え先です。

---

Also I found that other train companies use the phrase:

> 次は大手町　大手町　丸の内線　半蔵門線 **は** お乗り換えください

I assumed these two patterns ◯◯はお乗り換えです and ◯◯はお乗り換えください follow the same rule? Is there really a rule which would allow to freely replace ◯◯は(gerund)です with ◯◯は(imperative verb) and vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what's throwing you off, but お乗り換え here is used more like an adjective (“a transfer line”), not a verb (“you transfer here”). It's like saying “中央線 and 御堂筋線 are transfers” instead of saying “Please transfer for 中央線 and 御堂筋線”. The implications are the same, but the sentence is shorter. It's also a little less direct, because you can tie an action to the subject without explicitly asking the listener to act.

Phrases that feel similar to me:

- ゴミはお持ち帰りです (instead of ゴミはお持ち帰りください)
  Trash is take-home vs. Take home your trash
- 代金はレジでお支払いです (instead of 代金はレジでお支払いください)
  The charge is pay-at-the-register vs. Pay the charge at the register
- チケットはお引き換えです (instead of チケットはお引き換えください)
  Tickets are exchange vs. Exchange your tickets

---

Above answer only covers the "A線はお乗り換えです" construct. But isn't "丸ノ内線はお乗り換えください" a much more common way of using は? 詳細はお問い合わせください, お食事はテーブルをご利用ください, 個室はご予約ください… (For the Marunouchi Line, transfer. For details, ask. For dining, use the tables. For private rooms, make a reservation.)

Comment: Makes much more sense to me than an analysis of what words are "omitted".

Comment: @macraf My answer only covers the "A線はお乗り換えです" construct. But isn't "丸ノ内線はお乗り換えください" a much more common way of using `は`? 詳細はお問い合わせください, お食事はテーブルをご利用ください, 個室はご予約ください… (For the Marunouchi Line, transfer. For details, ask. For dining, use the tables. For private rooms, make a reservation.)

Comment: @macraf Sentence #1 is correct and impossible to misinterpret, but I can't give a straight yes–no answer to the latter two. They might be understood in context, but I'm not sure what they're supposed to mean. (Chatroom might help for more opinions/specifics)

Comment: @mirka You have addressed my concern even though I had not phrased the question correctly at the time. I edited my question and also your answer accordingly, please review if you accept the form, as I just copied your comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's a topic marker and the case of 中央線 and 御堂筋線 in the sentence is the subject. It says those who use 中央線 or 御堂筋線 are to change the train.

The terminology in the link is not really correctly used. 係助詞 is a term to categorize は も こそ as a group opposed to another group such as case particles: が を に へ で から より（よ）. It's a different perspective from functions like topic marker or such.

本町 called twice is just repetition.

Edit: I'm going to explain what "you can compose a sentence whose subject doesn't have logical coherence with the predicate" means.

1. The subject of the sentence doesn't have to be the agent of active voice or the recipient of passive voice. (Therefore, so called indirect passive is possible)
2. The predicate itself can be a whole clause. (You may be able to regard this phenomenon as double subjects)

As a result, you can write a sentence or a clause like 中央線が 乗客が 乗り換えだったら, if you need to specify the agent.

Comment: The subject of the sentence is 中央線 and 御堂筋線. What the sentence implies is that users of those lines should change the train. How I wrote it was bad, sorry.

Comment: Which gets me back to my original concern. What is the logic behind the announcement? Given は makes 中央線、御堂筋線 a subject, why isn't it a 「中央線、御堂筋線はお乗り換え先です」?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe those lines share the current line until it gets to 本町? Incidentally, お乗り換え先です sounds a strange expression because there are many passengers for whom those 乗り換え先 is not their destination. How subject or nominative case are used in Japanese is not necessarily the same as that in English. In Japanese, you can compose a sentence whose subject doesn't have logical coherence with the predicate like famous 僕はうなぎだ.

Comment: No, these lines do not share common tracks, why? I found the announcement exactly the same all over Japan. What is my concern here, is what grammatical rule (other examples) similar to this it follows. I see no problem with 僕はうなぎだ it translates roughly to "As far as I am concerned, an eel" (shorter in languages other than English). However interpreting the topic marker は for a train line in the same fashion "as for Central Line, a transfer" feels rather ridiculous.

Comment: I am even more confused with reasoning 「お乗り換え先です sounds a strange expression because there are many passengers for whom those 乗り換え先 is not their destination」 You can publish a dozen of 連絡先 on a company bulletin board. It does not mean everyone has to call each one in case of emergency. Is it different with 乗り換え先? You can't have more than one at a given station?

Comment: I meant many don't use 中央線・御堂筋線, sorry.

Comment: @macraf 「次は本町、本町です。中央線(か)、御堂筋線(に乗る場合)は、**ここで**お乗り換えです。」って感じで考えると、分かりやすいですか？

Comment: The problem of 乗り換え先 is that in contexts of railroad, it means a place that another train leads to.

Comment: "I found the announcement exactly the same all over Japan", I beg to differ as each Railway Company says the announcement differently. 東京メトロ{とうきょうめとろ} says something like 次{つぎ}は「九段下{くだんした}」、「九段下{くだんした}｣です。半蔵門線{はんぞうもんせん}、都営新宿線{とえいしんじゅくせん}にお乗{の}り換{か}える 客{きゃく}様{さま}はここで、お 降{お}りください。

Comment: @Shoko Your comment is the answer I was looking for. If は implies a contraction of 〇〇場合は then the whole structure makes sense.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder [Example from Tokyo Metro](https://youtu.be/af8GKOGliog?t=49s)

Comment: Oh, you are limiting it to only the automated announcements?

Comment: I get more used to when the conductor actually speaks than to the automated massages.

Not sure if it helps but here are a couple I found...

Hanzomon Line (Departing Shibuya for Kuki(Tōbu Isesaki Line)) - *次は表参道、表参道です。乗換のご案内です。銀座線・千代田線はお乗換ください*

Tōkyū Tōyoko Line [Tokyu] - (Departing Shibuya for Motomachi Chūkagai (Minatomirai Line) - *次は中目黒、中目黒です。日比谷線ご利用お客様はお乗換です*

Fukutoshin Line (Shibuya for Hannō(Seibu Line)) - *次は新宿三丁目、新宿三丁目です。乗り換えのご案内です。丸ノ内線・都営新宿線はお乗り換えください*