# What is the meaning of は in this context?

Tags: particles, particle-は

Context: A car approaches ルパン, 次元 asks over the radio who is in driving it

次元「ルパン、スコーピオンか？」

ルパン「いやぁ、違う。我が宿命のライバル。ご存じ警視庁**は**銭形警部さ」

I can't tell what は is supposed to mean in this context, is it the same meaning as の? If so, how common is this usage?

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28303/9831

Comment: I guess that answers it. I'd only ever seen this usage as country/state は city